# Drupal and Objective C Base 64 mismatch

Tags: ios, drupal-7, base64, nsdata

I have this sequence of bytes (printed from an HTML, so apologizes for the ugly format)

```
193<br/>250<br/>194<br/>129<br/>62<br/>60<br/>12<br/>171<br/>199<br/>96<br/>13<br/>125<br/>166<br/>175<br/>80<br/>85<br/>137<br/>29<br/>15<br/>189<br/>33<br/>231<br/>237<br/>98<br/>165<br/>35<br/>75<br/>250<br/>181<br/>150<br/>35<br/>175<br/>129<br/>174<br/>13<br/>13<br/>121<br/>229<br/>30<br/>173<br/>112<br/>210<br/>2<br/>165<br/>110<br/>113<br/>141<br/>166<br/>102<br/>105<br/>33<br/>82<br/>220<br/>233<br/>118<br/>36<br/>73<br/>88<br/>196<br/>152<br/>15<br/>231<br/>164<br/>119<br/>
```

When I use the Drupal function: `[_password_base64_encode][1]` I get the following base64 string:

```
/fjk/u1DAgulUpETay8IJZM5DoP6briMZCmGuLfZXwOUiqE1tJi5h0bo0IePlpcdaZK6GlRuqFGGMFAaDQCdr/
```

But when I use this sequence of bytes in my iOS application with the code:

```
NSString *base64Encoded = [hash base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

I get:

```
wfrCgT48DKvHYA19pq9QVYkdD70h5+1ipSNL
```

Why this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ported the function `_password_base64_encode` to iOS:

```
- (NSString*)drupalBase64PasswordEncode:(NSData*)data {
    NSUInteger count = [data length];
    int i = 0;
    NSString *itTo64String = @"./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const char *itTo64 = [itTo64String cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    char *input = [data bytes];
    NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    do {
        unsigned char value  = (unsigned char)input[i++];
        int value2;
        unsigned char toInsert = itTo64[value & 0x3f];
        [output appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , toInsert]];
        if (i < count) {
            value2 = value | ((unsigned char)input[i] << 8);
        }
        toInsert = itTo64[(value2 >> 6) & 0x3f];
        [output appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , toInsert]];
        if (i++ >= count) {
            break;
        }
        if (i < count) {
            value2 = value2 | ((unsigned char)input[i] << 16);
        }
        toInsert = itTo64[(value2 >> 12) & 0x3F];
        [output appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , toInsert]];
        if (i++ >= count) {
            break;
        }
        toInsert = itTo64[(value2 >> 18) & 0x3F];
        [output appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c" , toInsert]];
    }while(i < count);
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that you're encoding junk along with your intended string - can you dump the actual string that gets encoded, such as

```
$string = ' ... ';
var_dump($string);
$base64_string = _password_base64_encode($string);
var_dump($string);
```

It is most likely that you are including different characters ( breaks, newlines in different format, etc ) than you intended when encoding.

In addition, you might want to compare the output with PHP's native [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) function, and compare results.

Comment: Yes, Drupal using a "special" function to encode base 64. I'll copy it ported to iOS in the answer. Thanks